# htaccess unwanted redirect to a page non in folder

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have created an htaccess

I have these htaccess redirect rules for redirect some pages as **first level** and other as **in folder** pages. The problem is that with these rules are created some second level pages (from first level pages name):

`RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$  content.php?name=$1 [L]`

**for first level pages:** and I get correct url

mywebsite/mypage1

mywebsite/mypage2

mywebsite/mypage3

**and**

`RewriteRule ^sector/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$  category/index.php?name=$1 [L]`

**for in folder pages:** and I also get correct url

mywebsite/sector/mysectorpageA

mywebsite/sector/mysectorpageB

mywebsite/sector/mysectorpageC

**My problem is that are also created unwanted url first level page name:**

mywebsite/sector/mypage1

mywebsite/sector/mypage2

mywebsite/sector/mypage3

**Thanks in advance for any help**

Comment: What do you mean, “created”? Created where?

Comment: (Do you perhaps mean, that the links you have in your HTML “suddenly” don’t point to the correct location any more? Well if you change the base URL of your document, that of course has an effect on all _relative_ URLs that need to get resolved against it. The common solution would be to have all your relative URLs start with a `/`, so that they become relative to the domain root.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I use absolute url and I mean that with the rules that I use it is created (if I write it in the browser) also this url mywebsite/sector/mypage1 which refers me to a blank page because the real existing url is mywebsite/mypage1

Comment: Well `sector/mypage1` fits the pattern `^sector/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$`, so I am not sure what exactly you _expected_ to happen?

Comment: but I dont' want sector/mypage1 because mypage1 is in root folder then in sector folder I have pagea..pageb...

Comment: Still unclear what you actually mean. _Where_ are these URLs “created”?

Comment: when in browser I write mywebsite/sector/mypage1 I get a blank page because mypage1 not exist in sector folder, exist only in root folder... I want that if someone write mywebsite/sector/mypage1 get a 404 error

Comment: Why would you get a blank page? You should get whatever your `category/index.php` returns, because that is what you are rewriting this to …

Comment: _“I want that if someone write mywebsite/sector/mypage1 get a 404 error”_ - that decision should probably be made inside of `category/index.php` then.